# vTiger CRM 6 + LDAP Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, vtiger

I exploited the last days, but I wasn't able to find a real useful tutorial to intigrate LDAP Authentication into a vTiger CRM 6 (running on a Linux CentOS 6.5 distribution).

Any one experienced out here or some people who might share some useful manuals ?

Answer (score 0):

Make directory into your crm destination:

/var/www/html/crm/modules/Users/authTypes/

Then, Download the ldap file from :

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/adldap/adLDAP/adLDAP_4.0.4/adLDAP_4.0

Just open and customize the settings for your needs. The following settings match those needed for a 2012R2 Active Directory.

```
...
class adLDAP {

    /**
     * Define the different types of account in AD
     */
    const ADLDAP_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 805306368;
    const ADLDAP_WORKSTATION_TRUST = 805306369;
    const ADLDAP_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST = 805306370;
    const ADLDAP_SECURITY_GLOBAL_GROUP = 268435456;
    const ADLDAP_DISTRIBUTION_GROUP = 268435457;
    const ADLDAP_SECURITY_LOCAL_GROUP = 536870912;
    const ADLDAP_DISTRIBUTION_LOCAL_GROUP = 536870913;
    const ADLDAP_FOLDER = 'OU';
    const ADLDAP_CONTAINER = 'CN';

    /**
    * The default port for LDAP non-SSL connections
    */
    const ADLDAP_LDAP_PORT = '389';
    /**
    * The default port for LDAPS SSL connections
    */
    const ADLDAP_LDAPS_PORT = '636';

    /**
    * The account suffix for your domain, can be set when the class is invoked
    *
    * @var string
    */
        protected $accountSuffix = "@cortoso.com";

    /**
    * The base dn for your domain
    *
    * If this is set to null then adLDAP will attempt to obtain this automatically from the rootDSE
    *
    * @var string
    */
        protected $baseDn = "";

    /**
    * Port used to talk to the domain controllers.
    *
    * @var int
    */
    protected $adPort = self::ADLDAP_LDAP_PORT;
    /**
    * Array of domain controllers. Specifiy multiple controllers if you
    * would like the class to balance the LDAP queries amongst multiple servers
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $domainControllers = array("dc01.cortoso.com", "dc02.cortoso.com");

    /**
    * Optional account with higher privileges for searching
    * This should be set to a domain admin account
    *
    * @var string
    * @var string
    */
    protected $adminUsername = "ldap-binduser";
    protected $adminPassword = "super-password";

    /**
    * AD does not return the primary group. http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=321360
    * This tweak will resolve the real primary group.
    * Setting to false will fudge "Domain Users" and is much faster. Keep in mind though that if
    * someone's primary group is NOT domain users, this is obviously going to mess up the results
    *
    * @var bool
    */
        protected $realPrimaryGroup = false;

    /**
    * Use SSL (LDAPS), your server needs to be setup, please see
    * http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=ldap_over_ssl
    *
    * @var bool
    */
        protected $useSSL = false;

    /**
    * Use TLS
    * If you wish to use TLS you should ensure that $useSSL is set to false and vice-versa
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    protected $useTLS = true;

    /**
    * Use SSO
    * To indicate to adLDAP to reuse password set by the brower through NTLM or Kerberos
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    protected $useSSO = false;

    /**
    * When querying group memberships, do it recursively
    * eg. User Fred is a member of Group A, which is a member of Group B, which is a member of Group C
    * user_ingroup("Fred","C") will returns true with this option turned on, false if turned off
    *
    * @var bool
    */
        protected $recursiveGroups = true;

    ...
?>
```

To be able to test adLDAP, it is much easier to write a small php sniplet than doing it directly with vTiger CRM. Just create a small adldap_test.php file, in the same directory where adLDAP.php resides, with following content:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(FILE) . '/adLDAP.php');

try {
    $adldap = new adLDAP();
}

catch (adLDAPException $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit();
}
$authUser = $adldap->authenticate('user-to-authenticate', 'users-password');
if ($authUser == true) {
  echo "User authenticated successfully";
}
else {
  // getLastError is not needed, but may be helpful for finding out why:
  echo "\n";
  echo $adldap->getLastError();
  echo "\n";

  echo "User authentication unsuccessful";
}

echo "\n";
$result=$adldap->user()->infoCollection('ldap', array("*"));
echo "User:\n";
echo $result->displayName;
echo "Mail:\n";
echo $result->mail;

?>
```